# Java with matisse in netbeans - can't implement WindowListener

Tags: java, swing, matisse, windowlistener

UPD: Solved!

Good day!

I started develop JAVA GUI apps in netbeans 6.9.1 (I use matisse). So I decided to implement windowListener in my program but I have met the problem. I can’t access to the main frame!

Does anyone know how to deal with that problem?

UPD:
I don't get any exceptions and etc. I can't add listener for main frame because i don't know to to get access!

Here is example of generated code:

```
public class INotePadView extends FrameView 
{

  public INotePadView(SingleFrameApplication app)
  {
      super(app);

      initComponents(); //autogenerated method, nothing interesting.

      // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
      ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
      int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
      messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              statusMessageLabel.setText("");
          }
      });

      messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
      int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
      for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
          busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
      }

      busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
              statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
          }
      });

      idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
      statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
      progressBar.setVisible(false);

      // connecting action tasks to status bar via TaskMonitor
      TaskMonitor taskMonitor = new TaskMonitor(getApplication().getContext());
      taskMonitor.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
          public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
              String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
              if ("started".equals(propertyName)) {
                  if (!busyIconTimer.isRunning()) {
                      statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[0]);
                      busyIconIndex = 0;
                      busyIconTimer.start();
                  }
                  progressBar.setVisible(true);
                  progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
              } else if ("done".equals(propertyName)) {
                  busyIconTimer.stop();
                  statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
                  progressBar.setVisible(false);
                  progressBar.setValue(0);
              } else if ("message".equals(propertyName)) {
                  String text = (String)(evt.getNewValue());
                  statusMessageLabel.setText((text == null) ? "" : text);
                  messageTimer.restart();
              } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                  int value = (Integer)(evt.getNewValue());
                  progressBar.setVisible(true);
                  progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                  progressBar.setValue(value);
              }
          }
      });

  }

  @Action
  public void showAboutBox() {
      if (aboutBox == null) {
          JFrame mainFrame = INotePadApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
          aboutBox = new INotePadAboutBox(mainFrame);
          aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
      }
      INotePadApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
  }

//Other generated code
```

ANSWER:
I found the way how to solve this problem.

```
WindowListener winListener = new TestWindowListener();
    JFrame mainFrame = super.getFrame();
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(winListener);
```

I think that it could be useful for someone.

Comment: do you get any exception or any error?

Comment: Some information on where/how you are doing this would be very helpful.

Comment: What are you useing? Plain Swing JFrame? Swing Application Framework? Netbeans Platform?

Comment: As I understand the question: matisse doesn't provide access to the "main frame" so he doesn't know how to add a listener there (using matisse only).

Comment: Andreas_D you are right! I use matisse to create buttons and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Javadoc for the application framework (hard to find, but it's [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication.html)) :

```
WindowListener winListener = new TestWindowListener();
JFrame mainFrame = app.getMainFrame();
mainFrame.addWindowListener(winListener);
```